# ¿Cómo paso por referencia un array bidimensional?

Tags: c, array, fórmulas-de-matriz

Para mi ejercicio EN C, tengo que usar un array bidimensional dinámico de caracteres. En mi Main declaro el array char **posicio_taulell, después lo paso por referencia en la función novaPartida. 
En este momento no se si debo pasarlo como novaPartida(&posicio_taulell) o novaPartida(posicio_taulell)
Después lo vuelvo a pasar por referencia en otra subfunción donde no se si debo utilizar el '&' y dentro de esta subfunción ya pido el número de elementos y hago todos los malloc y comprovaciones. Además inicializo todos los valores del array y seguidamente en esa subfunción muestro por pantalla el elemento [0][0] y funciona perfectamente, pero luego en la función main y en la primera función al mostrar el elemento [0][0] me muestra un '4' cuando el elemento [0][0] es un '0'.

En la función main declaro el array bidimensional además en la función novaPartida lo quiero pasar por referencia para poder trabajar con el en futuras funciones. No se si debo poner el '&'

[image]
[image: Esta es la cabecera de la función novaPartida, no se si es correcta]

[image: Dentro de la función novaPartida quiero crear otra función donde necesito volver a pasar el array por referencia y no se si usar el '&']

[image: Esta es la cabecera de la función extreuDadesTaulell donde no se si usar el '&' para pasarlo por referencia el array. Aquí dentro hago los malloc y inicializo todas las posiciones]

[image: array]

Aquí se observa como dentro de la subfunción me muestra el elemento [0][0] correcto que es el '0' mientras que en la función main me muestra un '4' para la misma posición del

Comment: Tendrías que editar tu pregunta y poner el código y advertencias como texto en vez de imágenes.

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo por aquí

Comment: No, no agradezcas, solo hazlo si lo crees conveniente.